# search and replace using regular expressions in java

Tags: java

I need to find and replace all dates present inside a document(basically bring it to present date). The problem in using regex is if the date is in this format

```
CreationDatetime="2012/07/24 10:00:19 649 GMT"
```

the regex will not find this entry as the date is attached to another string. Is there any other way to find dates in all formats (    yyyymmdd, yyyy/mm/dd etc.) and bring it to the current date.

working code for search for one format (yyyymmdd) but the replace doesn't work now.

```
String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re2="((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3}))[-:\\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1})))(?![\\d])"; // YYYYMMDD 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);



    for(Object s : x){
        String temp = s.toString();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s.toString());
        if (m.find())
        {
            temp.replaceAll(re1+re2, "test");
            System.out.println(temp.toString());
        }
```

Comment: All formats as in every possible conceivable format that someone might have used or made up, or only standard formats?  Can you make a list of all formats used in the document along with how to separate it from the surrounding text?  If you can't, no magical regex or parser is going to catch every one exactly right either.

Comment: I basically want to search for the two formats mentioned inside brackets: yyyymmdd, yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?  Searching for `yyyy/mm/dd` should match your sample string just fine.

Comment: Are all the dates tagged with CreationDateTime?

Comment: Well as I mentioned in the description, the date is attached to another string (no spaces between them). regex is not able to find that.

Comment: @assylias, No. They can be with any other tag.

Comment: Regex works exactly fine for strings contained inside other strings.  Just don't include anchors like `^` or `$` to expect to match the entire string.  For example: http://www.rubular.com/r/ffiLCHp50B

Comment: Regex can find Strings embedded in other Strings, that's what they're for. If you could include you regex or better yet a working code sample we could point to you what's wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am able to find the word now but replace is somehow not working.

Comment: Is this just a case of needing to do `temp = temp.replaceAll(re1+re2, "test");`?

Comment: It is now as I figured out the answer myself. But i still can't do a replaceAll.